Why are some Battle Thanks Gifts empty?
In Pokemon TCGP you have the ability to "thank" your opponent after a Versus battle which gives them a claimable gift (a single Shop Ticket at this time).  However, I've noticed after some time these "thanks" gifts stop earning Shop Tickets.  Why is this the case?  Is there a limit to the number of Shop Tickets you can earn via Versus battles per day?


Yes, there's a limit of Shop tickets you can claim per day.
According to Game8:

If you receive a Thanks from another player after a Battle or Wonder Pick, you will obtain 1 Shop Ticket.
You can also get Shop Tickets if other players like your displayed binders or display boards under Community Showcase in the Social Hub.
However, keep in mind you can only get 5 tickets per day through likes or thanks.

